# Checkbox angular material modify styles without (deprecated) /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep

Tags: checkbox, angular-material, angular5

How modify the style of the mat-checkbox component is a checkbox angular material, before. I had them modified with ::ng-deep and it worked but recently I saw in the angular page that it is obsolete and will soon be removed from browsers: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

I also can't use encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None because styles could affect the global page

Answer (score 0):

Add your styles to global styles in assets folder if you have it configured in angular.json, else in styles.css in src folder.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the "ViewEncapsulation.None", wrap the parent component with a 
"div id = 'ccb'" and all styles affected by the problem, put the name of the div in front
"#ccb.mydp {}"